# MD5 Implementation produces the wrong result when hashing "test"

Tags: c#, hash, md5

I'm attempting to code my own implementation of the MD5 hashing algorithm in C#. I have gotten my algorithm to produce a hash, but it doesn't match the one I am expecting. For example, when I hash the string "test":

```
ff9dc1ed49568b10c3c6e09053ea4317 -- my implementation's result
098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6 -- expected result
```

My code is below:

```
    public class general
    {
        public static string numToBinary(int charCode, int idealLength)
        {
            string toReturn = Convert.ToString(charCode, 2);
            int numAdd = idealLength - toReturn.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < numAdd; i++)
            {
                toReturn = "0" + toReturn;
            }

            return toReturn;
        }

        public static string padZero(string str, int numZeroes)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numZeroes; i++)
            {
                str += "0";
            }

            return str;
        }

        public static string padZeroLeft(string str, int numZeroes)
        {
            string reversed = (string)str.Reverse();
            reversed = padZero(reversed, numZeroes);
            return (string)reversed.Reverse();
        }

        public static string[] getChunks(string totalString, int chunkLength)
        {
            int numOfChunks;
            numOfChunks = totalString.Length / chunkLength;
            string[] chunks = new string[numOfChunks]; //Create a new array to hold the chunks
            string currentChunk;

            for (int i = 1; i <= numOfChunks; i++)
            {
                currentChunk = totalString.Substring(i * chunkLength - (chunkLength), chunkLength);
                chunks[i - 1] = currentChunk;
            }

            return chunks;
        }

        public static uint F(uint nB, uint nC, uint nD)
        {
            uint toReturn = (nB & nC) | ((~nB) & nD);
            return toReturn;
        }

        public static uint G(uint nB, uint nC, uint nD)
        {
            uint toReturn = (nD & nB) | ((~nD) & nC);
            return toReturn;
        }

        public static uint H(uint nB, uint nC, uint nD)
        {
            uint toReturn = (nB ^ nC ^ nD);
            return toReturn;
        }

        public static uint I(uint nB, uint nC, uint nD)
        {
            uint toReturn = nC ^ (nB | (~nD));
            return toReturn;
        }

        public static uint circularLeftShift(uint original, int shiftAmount) //Bitwise circular left shift
        {
            uint newNum = (original << shiftAmount) | (original >> (32 - shiftAmount));
            return newNum;
        }

        public static string makeUniformLength(string bits, int length)
        {
            int toAdd = length - bits.Length;
            bits = reverseString(bits);
            bits = padZero(bits, toAdd);
            bits = reverseString(bits);
            return bits;
        }

        public static string reverseString(string str)
        {
            char[] chars = str.ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse(chars);
            return new string(chars);
        }

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] s = { //Create array to specify per-round shift amounts
                      7, 12, 17, 22,  7, 12, 17, 22,  7, 12, 17, 22,  7, 12, 17, 22,
                      5,  9, 14, 20,  5,  9, 14, 20,  5,  9, 14, 20,  5,  9, 14, 20,
                      4, 11, 16, 23,  4, 11, 16, 23,  4, 11, 16, 23,  4, 11, 16, 23,
                      6, 10, 15, 21,  6, 10, 15, 21,  6, 10, 15, 21,  6, 10, 15, 21
                      };
            uint[] k = new uint[64]; //Create array with 64 unsigned integers

            Console.Write("Please enter a string to hash: ");
            string message;
            message = Console.ReadLine();

            string msgFinal = "";
            byte[] messageBytes;
            messageBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

            for (int i = 0; i < messageBytes.Length; i++) //Form string for all the values
            {
                msgFinal = msgFinal + general.numToBinary(messageBytes[i], 8);
            }

            //Console.WriteLine(msgFinal);

            for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
            {
                k[i] = (uint)Math.Floor(Math.Pow(2, 32) * Math.Abs(Math.Sin(i + 1)));
                Console.Write(Convert.ToString(k[i], 16) + "; ");
            } 

            uint a0 = 0x67452301;
            uint b0 = 0xefcdab89;
            uint c0 = 0x98badcfe;
            uint d0 = 0x10325476;

            msgFinal += "1"; //Append 1 to the message
            int over448 = (msgFinal.Length) % 448;
            int zeroesToAdd = 448 - over448;
            msgFinal = general.padZero(msgFinal, zeroesToAdd); // Pad the end of the message with enough zeroes to bring it to a multiple of 448
            Console.WriteLine("len: " + msgFinal.Length);

            int originalLength = message.Length * 8;
            //ulong toAdd = (ulong)originalLength % ()Math.Pow(2, 64);
            uint toAdd = (uint)originalLength;
            string toAddStr = Convert.ToString(toAdd, 2);
            Console.WriteLine("existing length: " + toAddStr.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("adding: " + (64 - toAddStr.Length));
            string toAddSecondary = general.padZero("", 64 - toAddStr.Length);
            toAddStr = toAddSecondary + toAddStr;

            Console.WriteLine(toAddStr);
            Console.WriteLine("Length of toadd: " + toAddStr.Length);

            msgFinal += toAddStr;
            string[] msgChunks = general.getChunks(msgFinal, 512);
            string[] subChunks;
            uint A, B, C, D;
            uint dTemp;
            uint F = 0;
            uint g = 0;
            Console.WriteLine(msgFinal);
            Console.WriteLine(msgFinal.Length);

            foreach (string chunk in msgChunks)
            {
                subChunks = general.getChunks(chunk, 32);
                A = a0;
                B = b0;
                C = c0;
                D = d0;

                for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
                {
                    if (i >= 0 && i <= 15) {
                        F = general.F(B, C, D);
                        g = (uint)i;
                    } else if (i >= 16 && i <= 31)
                    {
                        F = general.G(B, C, D);
                        g = (uint)((5 * i + 1) % 16);
                    } else if (i >= 32 && i <= 47)
                    {
                        F = general.H(B, C, D);
                        g = (uint)((3 * i + 5) % 16);
                    } else if (i >= 48 && i <= 63)
                    {
                        F = general.I(B, C, D);
                        g = (uint)((7 * i) % 16);
                    }

                    dTemp = D;
                    D = C;
                    C = B;
                    B = B + general.circularLeftShift((A + F + k[i] + Convert.ToUInt32(subChunks[g], 2)), s[i]);
                    A = dTemp;
                }

                a0 = a0 + A;
                b0 = b0 + B;
                c0 = c0 + C;
                d0 = d0 + D;
            }

            string aF, bF, cF, dF;
            aF = Convert.ToString(a0, 16);
            bF = Convert.ToString(b0, 16);
            cF = Convert.ToString(c0, 16);
            dF = Convert.ToString(d0, 16);

            string final = aF + bF + cF + dF;
            Console.WriteLine(final);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: MD5 is weak against hacking attack and rarely used in these days. Why don't you use recent version of SHA ?

Comment: Because this is not being used for an actual application, but rather for my own learning experience

Comment: oh, very good. Hope your great achievements !